# Checking value of other array inside a map

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, nested-loops, array.prototype.map

Here I have a map I am try to check values of `x` in `y` array which then should return `true` if it finds and `false` if it does not finds expected output `[true,false,true,false,false]` . According to my knowledge on index of `x[2]` and `y[2]` it should enter inside the `if(x[index]===y[j]){ condition = true}` and return `true` but I am getting `[true,false,false,false,false]`.

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const y = [90, 80, 3, 6, 1]


const result = x.map((i, index) => {

  for (let j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
    console.log(x[index], y[j])
    if (x[index] === y[j]) {
      condition = true
    } else {
      condition = false
    }
  }

  return (condition)
})


console.log(result)
```

Comment: You don't stop the loop after it finds any match, so you always get the last result. The whole `for` loop is just equivalent to `x[index] === y[y.length - 1]`.

Comment: How can you prove that it is just equivalent to x[index] === y[y.length - 1] , when I  console.log(x[index], y[j]) it is showing up all the values of the array

Comment: I can prove it easily - the loop doesn't stop. So, only the last iteration matters for the value of `condition`. The last iteration will have `j` equal to `y.length - 1`. Ergo, the only check that will be taken into account would be `x[index] === y[y.length - 1]`, since `index` is an invariant.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I still didn't get it may I the way I am understood  the nexted loop is wrong . What will the right solution for the above problem then

Comment: [Add more logging to see it better](https://jsbin.com/saxajucite/1/edit?js,console). You can also walk through the code with a debugger. The solution is to just stop the loop if you find a match. [Compare the output](https://jsbin.com/xihecogulo/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is this:

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const y = [90, 80, 3, 6, 1]


const result1 = x.map(el => y.includes(el))


console.log({result1})

// A more efficient one leverages the fast lookup of the `Set` data structure:

const ySet = new Set(y);
result2 = x.map(el => ySet.has(el))

console.log({result2})
```